# Script bash does not respect wait command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to do a script that does things on my linux computer but does not respects wait commands.

That's my code that does not work

```
cat file.txt | while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
do
    QUEST="$(./fi $line | grep -oE " fi " &> A.txt; echo $? >"$dir")" & proc=$!
    wait "$proc"
    read ret <"$dir"

    if [[ "$QUEST" != "" ]];then echo "$line" &>> A.txt; fi; unset QUEST;
done &> /dev/null & wait
```

It have to do one quest a time and save the output (that could exists or not).

Comment: If you're waiting immediately after running the command, it's just like running the command in the foreground.

Comment: @Barmar "If you're waiting immediately after running the command, it's just like running the command in the foreground." Code please. In this way I don't understand.

Comment: I mean you should not use `&` to run the program in the background. Just run it normally, since you don't want to do anything else before it finishes.

Comment: In what way is it not respecting `wait`? Note that you are setting `QUEST` in a  *subshell*, not your current shell, so `QUEST` is undefined when you check its value later in the loop.

Comment: @Barmar "I mean you should not use & to run the program in the background. Just run it normally, since you don't want to do anything else before it finishes." The background it's needed because it have to do a command a time

Comment: it wait the same also if it's not in background?

Comment: When you run a command in the foreground, the shell always waits for it to finish, you don't need to use `wait`.

Comment: Are you intentionally subjecting `$line` to word-splitting and pathname expansion, or are you assuming that `fi` will receive the entire vale of `$line` as a single argument?

Answer (score 4):

When you run a command in the background, it's run in a subshell. Any variable assignments are not visible in the original shell, so the assignment to `QUEST` doesn't work.

You don't need to do that in the background, since you're immediately waiting for the command to finish. Just run it normally.

```
while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
do
    QUEST="$(./fi $line | grep -oE " fi " &> A.txt)"
    ret=$?

    if [[ "$QUEST" != "" ]]
    then  echo "$line" &>> A.txt
    fi
done &> /dev/null < file.txt
unset QUEST
```

There's also no need to write `$?` to `$dir`. The exit status of a variable assignment from a command substitution is the exit status of the command.

Comment: @barman Ok good answer about the code that I can't bee seen an other thinks. But it has to wait since the previous line finished. In this way there are so much parallels processes. It have to do it one a time (i don't want parallels processes)

Comment: If `fi` runs child processes in the background, there's no way for the shell to wait for them. It can only wait for the processes it starts. You need to find a way to make `fi` wait for its children.

Comment: "If fi runs child processes in the background, there's no way for the shell to wait for them. It can only wait for the processes it starts. You need to find a way to make fi wait for its children". The question it's about this. You write an answer mutilated my code. **I need one process a time, not parallels processess**. Whe question it's about wait and you deleted all the wait. It's a word that has disappared from code

Comment: There are no parallel processes in my answer.

Comment: The shell runs everything sequentially unless you use `&` to put a command in the background.

Comment: But it has no control over the processes that the programs run by themselves.

Comment: @barman "There are no parallel processes in my answer. The shell runs everything sequentially unless you use & to put a command in the background". It's a big file. If i start it could shock my computer. I try and i say u if it works

Comment: It takes 100% of my cpu. Seems it does not respects waiting. So it's sequenced but strange.

Comment: I want to write "It takes 100% of my cpu. Seems it overlap subshells. So it's sequenced but strange."

Comment: I don't know what `fi` does, but the problem is in there, not with this script.

Comment: You know what fi does and you know everything. If there's a problem in there, no problem. No problem with the script no problem with none. Gimmi a beer or a drink. Luv ya help